# Switch between the back and front cameras

Tags: android, camera, rotation, android-camera

I'm using the sample camera2 google and works well.

But how can I switch the camera between back and front with a button?

```
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample. Para trocar, colocar != no lugar de ==.
            if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
                    == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                    mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

            // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
            // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
            // garbage capture data.
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    width, height, largest);

            // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }

            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
        // device this code runs.
        new ErrorDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_switch_camera:

            closeCamera();
            if (mCameraId.equals("0")) {
                mCameraId = "1";
            } else {
                mCameraId = "0";
            }
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) Camera2Demo.this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

and the function "closeCamera()" here

```
 private void closeCamera() {
    mSession.close();
    mSession = null;
    mCameraDevice.close();
    mCameraDevice = null;
}
```

Comment: The OP never came back, but I demo'd this exact code and it worked. This is precisely what  I needed .

Comment: This method will use the wrong aspect ratio for the front facing camera if front vs rear camera are different sizes / aspect ratios. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Thank you for this solution.This code is working good, on rotating the front camera and again rotating the back camera.But when clicking the save picture button it is not saving the picture when I using front camera.Back camera taking picture is working